# Java expression optimization

Tags: java, optimization

I have code that all over the place(probably 20-30 instances) does this:

```
<widget>.setVisible((condition == VIEW) || (condition == EDIT));
```

Logically I do understand that the Java compiler should and probably will optimize this to calculate it up front and simply use the calculated boolean.

My question is is there any way to actually verify that this is the case?

**CLARIFICATION**

`condition` is a `private` class member with no way to modify it past construction.

Comment: I would not rely on the compiler to optimize that away. While it is possible, it is quite complicated, only useful in certain circumstances: If `condition` is a method local variable is almost possible and maybe done. If not, that depends on the posibility of `condition` to change (by setVisible sideeffects, other threads etc.).

Comment: @Karlson: I don't think you have any idea of what kind of super-heavy artillery goes on under the hood when an (in)visible components changes its state and hence needs to become either visible or hidden.  If you think you need to optimize that check because you may end up calling this often, you're in big trouble because that's definitely not what's going to slow down your app...

Comment: Also your example seems quite questionable, the terms widget and `setVisible` let me assume that there is a costly GUI operation or something like that involved, which would make the effect of an optimized boolean expression invisible due to the vast difference in executed instrictions of such an expression in respect to usual GUI framework code.

Comment: Condition evaluation takes negligible time compared to execution of setVisible().
How many times a second does setVisible() is invoked? 20-30? Meanwhile, modern processor can compute that condition millions (if not billions) times a second.

Comment: @TacticalCoder I understand perfectly well that using tweezers to pick up a log is a useless endeavor and performance improvement of this piece wasn't the point of the question.  There are multiple instances where code similar to this is being used and being an annoyance and was going to be changed anyway.  This one is for my personal education.

Comment: The purpose of the question is not to improve performance of the app since I do know that it's going to be negligible but to educate myself.  There are better places to and better methods to improve performance in the app I was given to work on.

Comment: "My question is is there any way to actually verify that this is the case?" This does not answer that whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disassemble the class file with [javap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javap.html), e.g.

```
javap -c com.example.ClassName
```

to see the bytecode source. But why not just guarantee the optimization by extracting into a temp boolean variable?

Answer (score 1):

> is there any way to actually verify that this is the case?

You could *try* to verify this by looking at the bytecode disassembly, then at the machine code produced by HotSpot, etc.

However, I think this strategy is fraught with difficultly. It is also fragile, since the result depends on the compiler/JVM and on the exact nature of `condition` (is it local? a class member? `final`? `volatile`?)

If you care about the optimization for performance reasons [1], my advice would be to perform it manually, by factoring out the common expression.

[1] I assume that you've profiled the code, and know for a fact that this is a bottleneck.

Comment: Yes and it isn't one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Disassemble the byte code.

That said, these kinds of optimizations may be done at run time, may depend on the declaration of `condition`, depend on where the conditions are located, and so on. Tracking down optimizations such as this is non-trivial in all but the simplest use cases.